# What's common practice? Types placement

Tags: java, methods, types

Would you:

- add types above the main method and then initialize them under the method

  ```
  public class Main {
      private Person person;
      public void method() {
           person = new Person("Bob", 30);
  ```
- add types above the main method AND initialize them

  ```
  public class Main {
      private Person person = new Person("Bob", 30);
      public static void main(String[] args) {
  ```
- add types under the main method AND initialize them

  ```
  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Person person = new Person("Bob", 30);
  ```

I would like to know when you would use which way and why.
I appreciate any input!

Comment: These are not types. These are variable declarations.

Comment: [Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or **primarily opinion-based** may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The first will throw an error, your trying to access a non-static variable in a static method. The second might work, depending on the `Person` class. The third won't work because your using `private` in a method.

Answer (score 1):

a) The `private` modifier is not allowed inside a method, so your third example will not even compile.

b) Only your 2nd example actually compiles. The first one has a non-static member of class "Main" and you try to set it directly inside a static method.

c) The examples are not equal. The third one has a local variable in the method (assuming we ignore the `private` modifier), the other two have a member variable of "Main".

a&b vs. c depends on where you need your variable. If you only need it inside the method, declare it there.

a vs. b depends primarily on what readability and use cases. If you CAN initialize your variable there and if it doesn't lead to unreadable code, do it. Otherwise, do it in the constructor or any init method.

Personally, I tend to mostly declare final objects directly, non-final objects can be initialized elsewhere (because declaring them directly makes it look pretty final even if they aren't).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of common practice, because the three examples you gave actually have different meanings. So it's more a matter of understanding variable declarations.

A variable declaration is declaring the name, type and optionally, the initial content of a variable you need to use.

```
String s    = "abc";
↑      ↑    ↑
type   name initializer
```

Now take a look at a class definition:

```
class A {
   // Class body scope
}
```

Everything declared inside a type body (class, interface, enum) is a *member* of that type. Members include fields, methods and nested classes. Variable declarations in this scope (outside of any method) are *fields*, and they can be *instance fields* and *static fields*. If they have the modifier `static`, they are shared by all the members of the class and in fact can be used without having an actual instance of this class. If they don't have that modifier, then they are instance fields.

Instance fields can't be used without having an actual instance. So they are not available to static methods like `main`, only to instance methods. Thus, your first example won't work - `main` is trying to put a value in an instance field (as it doesn't have the word `static`).

In the second example, you're still creating an instance field, but this time you are giving it an initial value. This is fine - but you still won't be able to access this information from `main`. This is merely a field that will exist separately in every new `Main` object you will create (if you create one).

In the third example, you are creating the variable inside a method. In this case, the variable is not a field. It is a *local* variable. As such, it cannot have access modifiers such as `private` and `public`, because local variables are only accessible inside the method where they are declared (in fact, inside the *block* where they are declared).

But if you remove the access modifier, this will work, and you'll be able to use it in `main`, but not outside of `main`.

---

Generally, the question whether to give the variable an initializer or assign to it later on depends on whether it's a field or a local variable, whether it is `final` or not, `static` or not, and whether you have a meaningful value for it when you create it. For local variables, it's recommended:

- To declare it as close as possible to where it is going to be used.
- To give it a value as soon as a meaningful value can be given.

In practice this means that most of the time you'll have an initializer in local variable declarations, if only to avoid pesky "variable may not have been initialized" compiler warnings.

For fields, especially if they are declared `final`, you're going to need to initialize them as soon as possible, but not necessarily with an initializer. You might do so in a constructor (for an instance field), or in an initializing block (for a static field whose value needs to be determined by a complex operation).

Answer (score 0):

If the only place you need tha variable 'person' is your Main method, you should declare and initialize 'person' as you did in the third example.

If you need that somewhere else, I would say you can do whatever you want to, but don't switch between those to make your code readable.

Comment: The third example uses `private` inside of a function... that will generate a compile time error.

Comment: Yes, you are right and the first example does not work as well. I thought Bakuriu wanted to know how to handle variables in general and that is what I answered. Sorry if I was wrong or if that wasn't clear